# WordPress - Assign Meta Data to Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have a website which uses a custom post type of Treatments, which we're using the CPT-onomies plugin to link as a taxonomy to other custom post types.

We have another post type, Practitioners, which I need to link related treatments too, this part is easy. But we also need to enable them to save prices per treatment and have a POA (price on application) option too.

At the momement this is rather awkwardly coded with serialised arrays, which makes long work of manipulating and reporting on the data.

What's the easiest approach to adding these two extra fields to the custom post type?

Comment: Just to clarify, what I need to do is assign one or more related treatments to each practitioner, then set pricing for each of these treatments, which is unique to that practitioner.

Comment: Treatments do not have prices assigned to them directly, only per practitioner.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Pods (http://pods.io/). This plugin enables an interface to define custom post types with a lot of options.

Including relationships, so you can add records of POA, and then assign these to the pod Practitioners for instance.

Comment: I've installed that and set up a Treatments pod, with the POA, price and consultation fee fields, I've also added a Related Treatments field to the Practitioners pod.

Comment: What I get is the ability to link treatments to practitioners, but I can only set the price per treatment, I need to be able to set a different price for each treatment for each practitioner.

Comment: At the moment I set a price on the treatment post type and this is then the same for each practitioner, but it needs to be set per practitioner.

Comment: I've just played with bi-directional fiels, which link the fields in one pod to another, but this just means adding a treatment price for a practitioner updates the price assigned to that treatment for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by using ACF Pro, specifically repeater fields within a field group on the Practitioner page that allow them to select multiple Treatments and assign pricing to each one.